# Synchronization between MS-SQL on premise database and azure database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, data-synchronization, azure

Is there any stable way to synchronize a table between a MS SQL Server on premise database and a table in an Azure database?

So far i have found the following possibilities, but they are not stable:

1. [SQL Data Sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/)
2. [Transactional Replication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/)
3. Self written TSQL Script with Elastic Database Transactions(T-SQL is planned for a later time and .Net is not stable)

I use SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition. My problem with the first two methods is that they are not recommended for production use.
I expect suggestions from experienced people.

Comment: I don't see anything about [transactional replication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-using-transactional-replication/#comments) not being prod ready, can you include where you read this?  Also, what are your requirements for syncing data? How  much data?

Comment: Following on @JohnM's comment, Transactional Replication works just fine on a 300GB database on one of my customer's sites.